# What is the name of this constructor syntax?

Tags: c#, constructor

I am used to this syntax:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(forestEntry,filter);
```

and to this syntax:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
ds.SearchRoot = forestEntry;
ds.Filter = filter;
```

They are both just using different Constructors, no. 1 only works because a 2-argument constructor exist, and no. 2 only works because SearchRoot and Filter are not readonly after construction.

Now I was given code with this syntax:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher
                           {
                               SearchRoot = forestEntry,
                               Filter = filter
                           };
```

This should do the same as the examples above, but which Constructor is called and how does the program proceed then? Does this syntax have a special name? What would I have to add to my own classes to be able to construct them like this?

Comment: [**Object Initializer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: Why do you not learn the basic syntax of C#? That is the object initialization syntax. Pretty basic.

Comment: From the count of comments and edits to the answer below it seems that a complete answer is quite complicated, so it was really necessary to downvote the question on the grounds that it is "pretty basic"...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is equivelant of your second code. Compiler will translate it into:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
ds.SearchRoot = forestEntry;
ds.Filter = filter;
```

This is called [*object inializers*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). You can use the object initializer syntax with the public properties and fields of your class.The only exception to this is [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx) fields. Since they can only be initialized in the constructor you can't use them in an initializer.

In this case you need also a parameterless constructor because  this:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher
                       {
                           SearchRoot = forestEntry,
                           Filter = filter
                       };
```

is equivelant to:

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher() // note the parentheses
                       {
                           SearchRoot = forestEntry,
                           Filter = filter
                       };
```

So you are calling the parameterless constructor. You can also use object inializers with other constructors as noted in the comments.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth saying something about the impact on read only fields.

Comment: A "public parameterless constructor" is *not* a requirement to use object initializers.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yes it is required. otherwise that code won't be valid `DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();`.

Comment: @Selman22: No, it is not required; a constructor call like `MyClass c = new MyClass("Some string") { OtherProperty = "Another string" };` is perfectly valid, if the respective constructor and properties exist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yes but in OP's code it uses the default constructor and it will give an error if you don't have parameterless constructor. but I think I should note that separately.

Comment: @Selman22: Indeed. Maybe clarify whether and where you are specifically talking about the OP's code example, and where you are talking about the *object initializer* syntax in general.

Comment: The compiler actually enforces atomicity & translates an object initializer to `temp = new DirectorySearcher(); <set properties>; ds = temp;` to ensure another thread cannot access `ds` in a state when the initializer properties have not all been set.